# Object required error testing Outlook

Tags: object, if-statement, vbscript, outlook, qtp

I am new to QTP and VBScript, can anybody advise me of the error on this script at the line 'If myEmails = Nothing' which says 'object required'? Also any general feedback or improvement tips would be appreciated, I have spent way too long trying to get this script working now lol!

```
myEmails = ""
If emailSubjectToSearch = "[A-Za-z0-9_]" Then
Set myEmails = emails.Find("[Subject] = "& emailSubjectToSearch & "") 
Else
If emailBodyToSearch = "[A-Za-z0-9_]" Then
Set myEmails = emails.Find("[Body] = "& emailBodyToSearch & "") 
Else
If emailSenderNameToSearch = "[A-Za-z0-9_]" Then
Set myEmails = emails.Find("[SenderName] = "& emailSenderNameToSearch & "") 
Else
If emailSentOnToSearch = "[A-Za-z0-9_]" Then
Set myEmails = emails.Find("[SentOn] = "& emailSentOnToSearch & "")
Else
If emailAttachmentToSearch = "[A-Za-z0-9_]" Then 
Set myEmails = emails.Find("[Attachment] = "& emailAttachmentToSearch & "")
End If
End If
End If
End If
End If


If myEmails Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "Email not found"
Else
MsgBox "Email found"
msgbox myEmails
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't know about the entire script, but the following code snippet should work

```
myEmails = ""
If emailSubjectToSearch = "[A-Za-z0-9_]" Then
Set myEmails = emails.Find("[Subject] = "& emailSubjectToSearch & "") 
ElseIf emailBodyToSearch = "[A-Za-z0-9_]" Then
Set myEmails = emails.Find("[Body] = "& emailBodyToSearch & "") 
ElseIf emailSenderNameToSearch = "[A-Za-z0-9_]" Then
Set myEmails = emails.Find("[SenderName] = "& emailSenderNameToSearch & "") 
ElseIf emailSentOnToSearch = "[A-Za-z0-9_]" Then
Set myEmails = emails.Find("[SentOn] = "& emailSentOnToSearch & "")
ElseIf emailAttachmentToSearch = "[A-Za-z0-9_]" Then 
Set myEmails = emails.Find("[Attachment] = "& emailAttachmentToSearch & "")
End If

If IsNull(myEmails) Then
MsgBox "Email not found"
Else
MsgBox "Email found"
msgbox myEmails
End If
```

Comment: `IsNull` is only used with database connections and fields. It cannot be used on objects that do not have a reference. Using `IsNull` with objects can result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I tried the IsNull method which yes got the msgbox to pop up as email found but was not populated, for some reason it is not being set by the look of it but I can't work out why it is not being SET by the IF ELSE statements. My aim is to get myEmails SET within the IF ELSE statements. Do I have to SET it to something before it enters the IF ELSE in order to change it to something else within there?

Comment: I have also tried doing the below instead of the ELSE IF statement but I got object variable not set error on the SET line.
Dim myEmails
Set myEmails = emails.Find("[Subject] = "& emailSubjectToSearch & "SearchText") & ("[Body] = "& emailBodyToSearch & "SearchText") & ("[SenderName] = "& emailSenderNameToSearch & "SearchText") & ("[SentOn] = "& emailSentOnToSearch & "SearchText") & ("[Attachment] = "& emailAttachmentToSearch & "SearchText")

Comment: I actually suspect it is to do with this because if I add a msgbox emails below it I get error of 'Invalid Procedure call or argument'.

`code`
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olns = olApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = olns.GetDefaultFolder(6)
Set emails = Inbox.Items
`code`

Answer (score 0):

Testing on a `null` reference in VBScript is done by `Is Nothing`. The `Is` operator is comparable to `===` in other languages as Javascript.

```
Dim myObject ' uninitialized primitive with value empty (do not confuse with "" or 0)
Set myObject = new Regexp  ' Now it has an object

Dim yourObject
Set yourObject = Nothing

If myObject Is Nothing then
    MsgBox "MyObject is Nothing" ' won't be displayed
End if
If yourObject Is Nothing then
    MsgBox "YourObject is Nothing" ' this is displayed
End if

Set yourObject = New RegExp
MsgBox (myObject Is yourObject) ' displays False

Set yourObject = myObject
MsgBox (myObject Is yourObject) ' displays True

Set myObject = Nothing
MsgBox "myObject: " & (myObject Is Nothing) & _
     & ", yourObject: " & (yourObject Is Nothing)
' Displays myObject: True, yourObject: False
```

Use the

```
If Not (myObject Is Nothing) Then ...
```

construct to test if a variable contains a non-null object.

And use the

```
If IsObject(myObject) Then ...
```

construct to test if a variable contains a primitive or an object